# Count Query Size to see if an insert exists

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery

I am using qt creator and I have a database with table student, lesson and enroll.

```
Student (name, lastname, semester, studentid) 
Lesson (name,lessonid)
Enroll (idofstudent,idoflesson,grade)
```

I want the user to have the option to add a grade for every student in separete lessons so i created some QlineEdits connected with a Qbutton that inserts into enroll the id of the student, the id of the lesson and his grade.

Problem is that i want to check if the student id user inserts in qlineedit is in my database. If not the insert shouldnt be done as there isnt any student with that id.

Creation of database:

```
#include "database.h"
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

Database::Database()
{
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("students.db");
    db.open();
    QSqlQuery q(db);
    q.exec(QString("DROP TABLE student;"));
    q.exec(QString("DROP TABLE lesson;"));
    q.exec(QString("DROP TABLE enroll;"));

    q.exec(QString("create table if not exists student(")+
                        QString("id integer primary key autoincrement,")+
                        QString("name varchar(1024),lastname varchar(1024),semester integer,")+
                        QString("studentid integer)"));

    q.exec(QString("create table if not exists lesson(")+
                        QString("id integer primary key autoincrement,")+
                        QString("lname varchar(1024),")+
                        QString("lessonid integer)"));

    q.exec(QString("create table if not exists enroll(")+
                        QString("id integer primary key autoincrement,")+
                        QString("idofstudent integer, idoflesson integer,")+
                        QString("grade double)"));
}
```

Check if student exists. In some way i think here is the mistake as i dont really know if i count the sqlrows correctly.

```
int  Database::studentexists(int sid)
{
 QSqlQuery query(db);
 query.exec("SELECT name FROM student where studentid="+QString::number(sid));
 int numRows;
 numRows = query.size();
 return numRows;
}
```

My button of insert:

```
void    MainWindow::addSlot3()
{

    if(studentidEdit->text().isEmpty() || lessonidEdit->text().isEmpty() || gradeEdit->text().isEmpty())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","Empty fields");
        return;
    }


    if(mydb->studentexists(studentidEdit->text().toInt() == 0))
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","Student doesnt exist");
        return;
    }


    if(gradeEdit->text().toDouble() > 10)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","Check Grade");
        return;
    }

    Enroll E(studentidEdit->text().toInt(),lessonidEdit->text().toInt(),gradeEdit->text().toDouble());
    mydb->insertEnroll(E);
}
```

i have this mydb->studentexists(studentidEdit->text().toInt()==0) cause i think that studentexists should return "1" if it finds a field with the id user trying to add. So if its "1" the function continues with mydb->insertEnroll(E); Else it throws an error.

Problem is that even if an insert with that id user adds exists it returns the error message " Student doesnt exist".

Comment: ``select count(*)`` if you want to know how many things match.

Comment: I think you should've use `numRowsAffected()` instead of `size()` or as @manni66 posted.

Comment: Both didnt worked guys but thanks for your time. I did it like this:
int  Database::studentexists(int sid)
{
 QSqlQuery query(db);
 int numRows=0;
 query.exec("SELECT name FROM student where studentid="+QString::number(sid));
 while (query.next())
 {
     numRows++;
 }
 return numRows;
}